Azure Durable Function Generating and Storing Multiple Reports per Timer Trigger Execution
I have an Azure Durable Function that is scheduled to run daily using a timer trigger. The function orchestrates a series of activities to generate reports and upload them to Azure Blob Storage. However, I'm encountering an issue where multiple times reports are being generated and stored in the blob storage and receiving multiple emails for the same report for each timer trigger execution. But this occurs only some times.This should not happen, as I only need a single report per execution.
[Function("TimerTriggerFunction")]
public async Task TimerTriggerFunction(
    [TimerTrigger("0 16 * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo,
    [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient starter)
{
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("OrchestratorFunction");

    _logger.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
}

[Function("OrchestratorFunction")]
public async Task OrchestratorFunction(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var ids = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<int>>("GetAllIds");
    var chunkedIds = ids.Chunk(100);
    var summaryTasks = new List<Task<List<ReportSummary>>>();

    foreach (var chunk in chunkedIds)
    {
        summaryTasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<List<ReportSummary>>("ReadSummaryForMultiple", chunk));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(summaryTasks);
    var summaries = summaryTasks.SelectMany(x => x.Result).ToList();

    var chunkedSummaries = summaries.Chunk(100);
    var detailTasks = new List<Task<List<ReportSummary>>>();

    foreach (var chunk in chunkedSummaries)
    {
        detailTasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<List<ReportSummary>>("ReadDetails", chunk));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(detailTasks);
    summaries = detailTasks.SelectMany(x => x.Result).ToList();

    chunkedSummaries = summaries.Chunk(100);
    var extraDetailTasks = new List<Task<List<ReportSummary>>>();

    foreach (var chunk in chunkedSummaries)
    {
        extraDetailTasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<List<ReportSummary>>("ReadExtraDetails", chunk));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(extraDetailTasks);
    summaries = extraDetailTasks.SelectMany(x => x.Result).ToList();

    var result = await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>("SendSummaryEmail", summaries);

    stopwatch.Stop();

    _logger.LogInformation($"Completed summary report. Total time taken {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
}

[Function("SendSummaryEmail")]
public async Task<bool> SendSummaryEmail([ActivityTrigger] List<ReportSummary> summaries)
{
    if (summaries == null)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("No data to send.");
        return false;
    }

    var storageConnectionString = "storage_connection_string";
    var reportFolder = "report_folder";
    var containerName = "container_name";

    var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(storageConnectionString, containerName);
    var fileName = $"DataSummary_{DateTime.Now:ddMMyyyy_hhmmss}.csv";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));

    var uploadSuccess = await WriteDataAndUploadToBlob(summaries, containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName), filePath);

    if (!uploadSuccess)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Failed to upload data.");
        return false;
    }

    var sasUri = GenerateSasUri(containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName));

    if (sasUri == null)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Failed to generate SAS token.");
        return false;
    }

    var subject = "Report Subject";
    var content = "Report Content";
    var recipientEmails = GetRecipientEmails();

    await SendEmail(subject, content, recipientEmails, sasUri.ToString());

    return true;
}

private async Task<bool> WriteDataAndUploadToBlob(List<ReportSummary> data, BlobClient blobClient, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync("Id,Type");

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                var line = $"{item.Id},{item.Type}";
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);
            }
        }

        var response = await blobClient.UploadAsync(filePath);
        return response.GetRawResponse().Status == (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error writing and uploading data.");
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
    }
}


Additionally, my host.json configuration is as follows:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 100,
        "excludedTypes": "Request;Exception"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "maxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 2,
      "maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 3
    },
    "queues": {
      "maxDequeueCount": 5
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "03:00:00"
}


Issues:
1.Multiple times reports are being generated and uploaded to blob storage for each timer trigger execution,but this occurs only some times.
2.I need to ensure only one report is generated and stored per execution.
3.Additionally, I am receiving multiple emails for the same report, which is not intended.
Questions:
1.What could be causing the multiple report generations?
2.How can I modify my code or configuration to ensure only one report is generated and stored for each timer trigger execution?

what do you mean by multiple report in this and can you share the sample of multiple report?

By "multiple reports," I mean that the same report is generated and stored multiple times in Azure Blob Storage and sent via email multiple times for a single timer trigger execution.

Do you get this log message several times in the log as well? "Completed summary report...."

"Completed summary report. Total time taken ... "  this log message am getting only one time.

I wonder if your Orchestrator code isn't deterministic. The "deterministic" constraint means that the Orchestrator must run exactly the same way, each time it picks up after an activity. One possible violation of determinism is your use of Stopwatch, because the clock changes each time the Orchestrator resumes. Can you remove the Stopwatch code and try again? If that works, I'll write a proper answer explaining the mistake (and also why Stopwatch is not useful!) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints?tabs=csharp#dates-and-times

i tried by removing Stopwatch.
Same report is generated and stored multiple times in Azure Blob Storage
